# SQL Oracle, merging two result sets

Tags: sql, oracle, datatable

*I have two tables, there is no key to join them.*

**First Result:**

```
select fruit, sum(sales) from normal
group by fruit
```

**Expected Answer**

> ```
>  Red Apple        5000
>
>  Yellow Mango     7000
> ```

**Second Result:**

```
select fruit, sum(sales) from not_normal
group by fruit
```

**Expected Answer**

> ```
>  Green Apple   300
>  Green Mango   500
> ```

**Now I want the final result displayed in this format:**

[image]

*I can extract the Result 1 and result 2, and operate on Excel. But I want to know how I could do it in Oracle SQL.*

Comment: So you're sort of inventing a join condition based on the last word in the description? What if you have more than two types of apple (or any fruit...)?

Comment: I am not working with fruits, I am working with aircraft. But that was just an example.

Comment: It doesn't matter, my questions still stand; but it would be helpful if your data and results were at least representative of what you're trying to do. Forget Oracle and SQL (and Excel) for a moment and explain, in your question, how you would relate the two sets of data, as a human. If you can't explain the logic and the result you want then we don't have much hope of explaining how to achieve it - it's possible someone might guess and get lucky, but unlikely...

Comment: Fruits vs. aircrafts? I hope you aren't responsible of writing new software for Boeing 737 MAX 8.

Comment: They are results from two different tables with no keys. Usually in R, I can just column bind the result1 and result 2 and perform the arithmetic. In Excel, I can copy paste (result1 , result2) into one excel sheet and perform arithmetic operations. I wanted to know how I could do it on Oracle sql without having to export the data.

Comment: Littlefoot That's my opening bit at mic-nights. I m not responsible for whatever happened with the BOEINGs

Comment: I'm terribly sorry about what's going on with those aircrafts. When I produce a bug, nothing much happens (I blush for a moment and fix it), but their bugs are serious & expensive. I hope they'll fix it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know how it goes ... garbage in, garbage out.

```
SQL> with
  2  normal (fruit, sales) as
  3    (select 'red apple', 5000 from dual union all
  4     select 'yellow mango', 7000 from dual
  5    ),
  6  not_normal (fruit, sales) as
  7    (select 'green apple', 300 from dual union all
  8     select 'green mango', 500 from dual
  9    )
 10  select n.fruit as fruit,
 11         sum(n.sales) nsales,
 12         nn.fruit as fruit_1,
 13         sum(nn.sales) nnsales,
 14         regexp_substr(n.fruit, '\w+$') as fruits,
 15         sum(n.sales) + sum(nn.sales) sales
 16  from normal n join not_normal nn
 17    on regexp_substr(n.fruit, '\w+$') = regexp_substr(nn.fruit, '\w+$')
 18  group by n.fruit, nn.fruit
 19  /

FRUIT            NSALES FRUIT_1        NNSALES FRUITS                    SALES
------------ ---------- ----------- ---------- -------------------- ----------
red apple          5000 green apple        300 apple                      5300
yellow mango       7000 green mango        500 mango                      7500

SQL>
```

Comment: Littlefoot from the land before time series. Thanks. I just wanted the syntax to merge tables

Comment: Littlefoot, what is  " regexp_substr(n.fruit, '\w+$') " doing?

Comment: It selects the last (`$`) word (`\w+`) from the `n.fruit` string.

Comment: is it possible to remove characters instead of words. For example: `Apple2b to Apple`

Comment: " \Z Matches at the end of a string" but I need the last 2 characters or 3 characters.

Comment: If you need the last 2 characters, use `substr(n.fruit, -2)`; you don't need regular expressions for that.

Comment: I think it is substr(n.fruit, 1, length(n.fruit) -2)

Comment: Nope. That would return all characters except the last two.